# How to output external js file as inline script in wordpress?

Tags: javascript, wordpress, inline

I have a js file that I would like to output in my wordpress  section as inline js code.

For example I have this file: "//example.com/js/tracking.js" and I need code of this file to be printed inline between  in the site's head - To avoid fetching this file from the server separately.

Hope someone can help me.

Thanks

Comment: `echo "<script>" .  file_get_contents('//example.com/js/tracking.js') ."</script>"`

Comment: https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_add_inline_script/

Comment: "To avoid fetching this file from the server separately." - What do you mean by that? Just save the file locally and include it. If you use @Banzay 's code ^ it's still going to fetch the file from example.com